# Page and Posts loading as index page? Not loading the content

Tags: posts, menus, pages, navigation

I've been developing a website on wordpress for some time now and came across some issues but until now I could figure it out, not today... Yesterday I've worked some more on the website and today when I came back to do some more work the pages on my site that are part of my navigation menu didn't load properly (minus the home page that is static and a news page that is the index page), they were loading the index.php page. Also with my posts in the news(index) page the load the index page instead of the post content. The URLs appear correct, but the loaded page is the index one. This doesn´t happen with the other pages I have that are not in the navigation menu and also with some custom post types, everything works fine there. The strange thing is that it happened from nothing, maybe is a quick fix... or not, I'm not an expert.

Thank you in advance and if you could help me I would aprecciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, after trying a million things I tried one more, super stupid but it worked, I just went to permalink settings, clicked save changes and my posts and pages are working again... I don't understand why but finally it's working again.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with other themes also. If it is a problem with the current active theme, rectify it at the theme level.

First activate a default theme provided by WordPress. If it is working fine, then the issue is with your theme.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I checked with the wordpress provided themes and the problem continues, posts and pages still load as index.